# Accessing mainwindow.xaml.cs methods from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

hi i am relatively new at Wpf application

i want to know  that can i create a object of `mainwindow.xaml.cs`
in some other class
And then using that object  excess the user defined methods  in `mainwindow.xaml.cs`

i am trying to something like this 
it creates the object of mainwindow but can't access the method 
the method which i am trying to access is public defined

```
MainWindow window = new Mainwindow();
window.point_to_screen();
```

it gives this error

> Error  2   The type name 'point_to_screen' does not exist in the type 'System.Windows.Window'

Comment: Show `point_to_screen()` signature.

Comment: any compile time error displayed ? like 'MainWindow.point_to_screen()' is inaccessible due to its protection level. If point_to_screen() is public then you can access method.

Comment: are all the project references alright.. ? try do the same thing within a different project / solution setup . check if u get the same error

Comment: And this have the kinect tag because...

Comment: Please copy the code you are actually using. `MainWindow != Mainwindow`

Answer (score 7):

You should cast the current mainwindow to a MainWindow object.
If you create a new window you won't be able to acces your current open window

```
MainWindow wnd = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
wnd.point_to_screen();
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your method be in ***`public`*** protection level, and check if you use an instance method (not `static`) :

```
public class MainWindow 
{
...
    public void point_to_screen()
    {
       ...
    }
 }
```

and use it:

```
 MainWindow window = new Mainwindow();
 window.point_to_screen();
```

---

if you use a `static` method your code should be like this:

```
public class MainWindow 
{
...
    public static void point_to_screen()
    {
       ...
    }
 }
```

and use it:

```
 MainWindow.point_to_screen();
```